# git push --force by default

Tags: git

When I do a `git push`, git will do forced updates automatically if necessary, as if I had specified the `--force` option. I have configured this a long time ago. I don't want this behavior anymore, and can't find what is the configuration variable that affects this behavior. I can't find anything relevant in the `.gitconfig` or `.git/config` files.

EDIT: added my current config files:

my .gitconfig:

```
[user]
    name = xxxx xxxx
    email = xxxx
[core]
    excludesfile = /Users/xxxx/.gitignore_global
[difftool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = opendiff \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
    path = 
[mergetool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = /Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/opendiff-w.sh \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" -ancestor \"$BASE\" -merge \"$MERGED\"
    trustExitCode = true
```

local repo config:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://xxxx@xxxx.com/var/git/tw
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    push = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
[remote "AudioCopy"]
    url = /Users/xxxx/Src/AudioCopy/myacp
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/AudioCopy/*
[submodule "Sources/iPhoneInterface/SoundCloud/CocoaSoundCloudAPI"]
    url = git://github.com/soundcloud/CocoaSoundCloudAPI.git
[submodule "Sources/iPhoneInterface/SoundCloud/CocoaSoundCloudUI"]
    url = git://github.com/soundcloud/CocoaSoundCloudUI.git
[submodule "Sources/iPhoneInterface/SoundCloud/JSONKit"]
    url = git://github.com/nxtbgthng/JSONKit.git
[submodule "Sources/iPhoneInterface/SoundCloud/OAuth2Client"]
    url = git://github.com/nxtbgthng/OAuth2Client.git
[submodule "Sources/iPhoneInterface/SoundCloud/OHAttributedLabel"]
    url = git://github.com/nxtbgthng/OHAttributedLabel.git
[branch "linux"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/linux
```

remote repo config:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = true
```

sample run:

```
~/Src/tw % git push
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 394 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://xxxx@xxxx.com/var/git/tw
   26636fd..4247b2e  guile20 -> guile20
 + e80b72f...3578ee1 linux -> linux (forced update)
~/Src/tw %
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your `[remote "origin"]` config entry it looks like you've set up a mirroring push. If this is not what you wanted I would get rid of this line entirely. If you are happy with a mirror style push but don't want to force (this doesn't make a lot of sense to me), you want to remove the `+` prefix from the push line in the `[remote "origin"]` section of your local repository's config.

Alternatively:

```
git config --unset remote.origin.push
```

or:

```
git config remote.origin.push 'refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*'
```

depending on which choice you make.

Comment: That was it. Thanks a lot. I will consider the different options.